# QLabel allows file drag&drop, but QListWidget shows a 'file drop not allowed' indication

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QListWidget, QLabel


class FileDnD(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.listwidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.setFixedSize(300,300)
        
        self.qlabel = QLabel("drop",self)
        self.qlabel.setFixedSize(50,50)
        self.qlabel.move(50, 300)

        self.listwidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listwidget.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.listwidget.dropEvent = self.dropEvent

        self.qlabel.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.qlabel.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.qlabel.dropEvent = self.dropEvent

    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        file_paths = [url.toLocalFile() for url in event.mimeData().urls()]
        for file_path in file_paths:
            self.listwidget.addItem(file_path)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FileDnD()
    window.setFixedSize(300,400)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm experiencing an issue with file drag and drop functionality in my application.
It works perfectly with QLabel, but I'm facing a problem with QListWidget.
When I try to drag a file onto QListWidget, it shows a 'file drop not allowed' indication, and the file drop doesn't work.
I'm in need of some assistance to resolve this issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must also override `dragMoveEvent()`. Note that you should not use the same event handlers for different widgets. Either subclass and properly override each event handler, or use an event filter.

Comment: Also, as the [documentation says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), you should **always** use a central widget, and proper [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should also be used in any case. Create a central widget (a basic QWidget will suffice), set a layout for it, and add all your widgets to it.